# kdb: dynamically denormalize a table (convert key values to column names)

Tags: kdb

I have a table like this:

```
q)t:([sym:(`EURUSD`EURUSD`AUDUSD`AUDUSD);server:(`S01`S02`S01`S02)];volume:(20;10;30;50))
q)t
sym    server| volume
-------------| ------
EURUSD S01   | 20    
EURUSD S02   | 10    
AUDUSD S01   | 30    
AUDUSD S02   | 50
```

I need to de-normalize it to display the data nicely. The resulting table should look like this:

```
sym   | S01 S02
------| -------
EURUSD| 20  10 
AUDUSD| 30  50
```

How do I dynamically convert the original table using distinct values from server column as column names for the new table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you want 'pivot' table. Following page has a very good solution for your problem:
http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/pivoting-tables/

Here are the commands to get the required table:

```
  q) P:asc exec distinct server from t
  q) exec P#(server!volume) by sym:sym from t
```

Answer (score 1):

One tricky thing around pivoting a table is - the keys of the dictionary should be of `type` `symbol` otherwise it won't generate the pivot table structure.

E.g. In the following table, we have a column `dt` with `type` as `date`.

```
t:([sym:(`EURUSD`EURUSD`AUDUSD`AUDUSD);dt:(0 1 0 1+.z.d)];volume:(20;10;30;50))
```

Now if we want to pivot it with columns as dates , it will generate a structure like :

```
q)P:asc exec distinct dt from t
q)exec P#(dt!volume) by sym:sym from t
(`s#flip (enlist `sym)!enlist `s#`AUDUSD`EURUSD)!((`s#2018.06.22 2018.06.23)!30j, 50j;(`s#2018.06.22 2018.06.23)!20j, 10j)
```

To get the dates as the columns , the `dt` column has to be typecasted to `symbol` :

```
show P:asc exec distinct `$string date from t
`s#`2018.06.22`2018.06.23

q)exec P#((`$string date)!volume) by sym:sym from t
sym   | 2018.06.22 2018.06.23
------| ---------------------
AUDUSD| 30         50
EURUSD| 20         10
```